# 550 SMTP error : mailbox unavailable

Tags: email, smtp

I'm communicating with one company via e-mail. It worked a few days ago
but tommorrow I sent them an e-mail and I received e-mail with error message:

```
Your message for <name@company_name.com> from 2011/04/12 could not be delivered.
Reason:550 smtp; 550 5.7.0 Your server IP address is in the SORBS DNSBL database.
Mailbox unavailable.
```

Does it mean that something happened on their side? Could you explain me what happened?
What is SORBS DNSBL database?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the sending mail server has been blacklisted.

I suggest to start from

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_and_Open_Relay_Blocking_System